# Automatically save outputs variables in folder workspace using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, arc-hydro

I want to create python script with aim to import him in environment arcmap 10.1 and to make a hydrologic analysis

because the scipt meybe can have many outputs raster file or feature class would like to find a way for automatic save outputs variables in the folder workspace

for example

I want to import a raster file (Dem) and to take as export a 3 raster file from the command fill sinks, Fill Sinks,flow directions and flow accumulation from arc hydro toolbox

```
cl = my import dem
fill = output for Fill Sinks
fdr = output for flow directions
Fac = output for flow accumulation
```

and i want export them(3 raster) automatically saved to the folder workspace without definitive output parameters from the user

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")

# Local variables:
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
cl = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# Process: Fill Sinks
arcpy.FillSinks_archydrotools(cl, fill, "", "", "ISSINK_YES")
# Process: Flow Direction
arcpy.FlowDirection_archydrotools(fill, Fdr, "")
# Process: Flow Accumulation
arcpy.FlowAccumulation_archydrotools(Fdr, Fac)
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you just have to assign fill, Fdr and Fac the name you want to name those raster! They will be automatically saved to the arcpy.env.workspace.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Arc Hydro Tools.tbx", "archydrotools")

#Set Ouput Names
fill=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\OuputFillRasterName'
Fdr=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\OuputFdrRasterName'
Fac=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) + '\\OuputFacRasterName'

# Local variables:
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
cl = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# Process: Fill Sinks
arcpy.FillSinks_archydrotools(cl, fill, "", "", "ISSINK_YES")
# Process: Flow Direction
arcpy.FlowDirection_archydrotools(fill, Fdr, "")
# Process: Flow Accumulation
arcpy.FlowAccumulation_archydrotools(Fdr, Fac)
```